# error when build catkin package

Tags: catkin, catkin-package, build, roslib, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have already make a catkin work space following the [ROS tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/BuildingPackages). And I also have created a catkin package in source folder.
So next I tried to build the catkin package.
Everything works before I add the c++ source file into the source folder of the catkin package.
After I add the c++ source file, configuration step works fine. But next when I run "make" to build the package, this kind of error appears. It seems it cannot find ROS library.

```
CMakeFiles/joy_teleop_node.dir/src/joy_teleop_node.cpp.o: In function `TeleopTurtle::TeleopTurtle()':
joy_teleop_node.cpp:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::NodeHandle(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&)'
joy_teleop_node.cpp:(.text+0x2a2): undefined reference to `ros::Publisher::~Publisher()'
joy_teleop_node.cpp:(.text+0x366): undefined reference to `ros::Subscriber::~Subscriber()'
joy_teleop_node.cpp:(.text+0x443): undefined reference to `ros::Publisher::~Publisher()'
joy_teleop_node.cpp:(.text+0x470): undefined reference to `ros::Subscriber::~Subscriber()'
joy_teleop_node.cpp:(.text+0x4ae): undefined reference to `ros::Subscriber::~Subscriber()'
joy_teleop_node.cpp:(.text+0x4c0): undefined reference to `ros::Publisher::~Publisher()'
joy_teleop_node.cpp:(.text+0x4cf): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::~NodeHandle()'
```

This is package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
<name>joy_teleop</name>
<version>0.0.0</version>
<description>The joy_teleop package</description>
<maintainer email="quan1992@wpi.edu">adrian</maintainer>
<license>BSD</license>
<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
<build_depend>joy</build_depend>
<build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
<build_depend>turtlesim</build_depend>
<run_depend>joy</run_depend>
<run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
<run_depend>turtlesim</run_depend>
<export>
</export>
</package>
```

And this is CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(joy_teleop)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS joy roscpp turtlesim)
catkin_package(
INCLUDE_DIRS include
)
include_directories(include
${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_executable(joy_teleop_node src/joy_teleop_node.cpp)
```

I can build the source file using rosbuild method, but not catkin.

Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52409/error-when-build-catkin-package/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-01-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-01-15**:
Is this part of a tutorial? If so, can you tell us the URL of the tutorial so that someone can correct / add clarification to it?

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-01-16**:
Yeah, I have added the link to my question.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-01-16**:
Thanks. I modified wiki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since `undefined reference` indicates linker error in general in `C` and `C++`, you need to link your target to the appropriate libraries. Try adding the following to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
target_link_libraries(joy_teleop_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-01-16**:
Yeah! It works! Thank you very much!